# Non-daemonize Fork/Join pool

Tags: java, daemon, fork-join

How to create non-daemonize fork/join pool?
If I create pool in such way:

```
ForkJoinPool pool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool()
```

It'll stop all task when my program exit, what is proper way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` obtains the one common pool. It is only created once.

You can create your own [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool-int-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-boolean-) where you specify a thread factory which doesn't make the threads, daemon threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use executor thread pool which by default provides non-daemon threads.